# Perl - Linux - How can I make my "index.pl?see=this&foo=that&bar=that" url pretty? (index.pl/(see value)?

Tags: perl, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been reading and struggling to no avail.

I have a url like this: `http://my-domain.com/index.pl?see=this&foo=that&bar=that`

I would like ti to display like this:

```
http://my-domain.com/index.pl/this
```

Now let me throw this out there!

The "see" value needs to be the "friendly". But, the see could be positioned in a different spot in the url!

eg: `http://my-domain.com/index.pl?foo=that&see=this&bar=that`

(Could be accessed via `http://www` or without the www.)

I read a bunch of posts here and elsewhere but found nothing that explained this to me with an example I could understand.

I would even like to drop the ".pl" if even at all possible!

Sorry such a noob.. I need help.

Here is the whole htaccess file i have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.html$ /index.pl [L]
RewriteRule index/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.pl?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6
```

I was also trying to make index.html point to index.pl

Thanks..

Comment: Doubt this is a Perl question. What is your web server? Apache?

Comment: Yes, Apache. I mentioned perl because of the script being used for the query. I really need to learn more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off passing the URL parameters into the script and doing the rest of the processing there as it'll give you more flexibility and you'll be dealing with Perl instead of complicating your mod_rewrite rules. Something like this in your `.htaccess` file should do the trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/to/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^request(/.*)?$ /path/to/index.pl [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `RewriteCond` directives are there to prevent paths to existing files and directories from being rewritten.  If you *must* remove them, make sure the path to `index.pl` doesn't get rewritten or mod_rewrite will go into a loop on every request.

You can then grab everything off `$ENV{REQUEST_URI}` inside your `index.pl`, split the string at the slashes and validate and assign your arguments appropriately.

NB: I advise against using `index` for the request path because Apache's default configuration may override that keyword (as it does in my case).

Comment: ah, yes the $ENV{REQUEST_URI} better than using CGI! Amazing what you forget when you move to other languages (even if just briefly)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for mod_rewrite if you're using Apache.  It's got nothing to do with perl :)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score -1):

You could use a REST interface:

```
http://my-domain.com/index.pl/see/this
```

or

```
http://my-domain.com/index.pl/this
```

You basically have your index.pl script (or rename it to whatever you want) looking at the URL path at each request ($ENV{REQUEST_URI})